# How can I make this code more succinct

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I want to make my code more succinct without using the `replace()` method.

Write a function royalWe(sentence) that returns a string where:

- Every 'I' is replaced with 'we'
- Every word 'mine' is replaced with 'ours'
- Every word 'my' is replaced with 'our'
- Every word 'me' is replaced with "us"

Examples:

`royalWe("I want to go to the store")` => "we want to go to the store"
`royalWe("This is mine")` => "This is ours"
`royalWe("Jump for my love")` => "Jump for our love"
`royalWe("This is my house and you will respect me")` => "This is our house and you will respect us"

My Code:

```
function royalWe(sentence){
  var sent = sentence.split(" ");
  var newSent = [];
  var replaceWords = ["I","mine","my","me"];
  var words = ["we","ours","our","us"]

  for(var i = 0; i < sent.length; i++) {
      var idxofchar = replaceWords.indexOf(sent[i]);
      if(idxofchar !== -1) {
        var word = sent[i].split(sent[i]).join(words[idxofchar])
        newSent.push(word);
      } else {
        newSent.push(sent[i]);
      }

  }
  return newSent.join(" ");

}
```

Comment: If your code is functioning at the minute, and there's no problem, you might have better luck asking at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Questions asking for improvements to working code aren't on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use functional programming? Have you learned about it yet? If not, I suggest these exercises: [react.io functional JS](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)

Answer (score 0):

Using functional methods and no regular expressions, you would probably want to replace the `for` loop with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can also store the replacement strings as key-value mappings in an object, instead of in two parallel arrays.

```js
function royalWe(sentence) {
  var replacements = { I: "we", mine: "ours", my: "our", me: "us" };
  return sentence
    .split(" ")
    .map(function(word) { return replacements[word] || word; })
    .join(" ");
}

console.log(royalWe("I want to go to the store"));
console.log(royalWe("This is my house and you will respect me"));
console.log(royalWe("This is mine"));
console.log(royalWe("Jump for my love"));
```

If you were to use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), it would be more efficient and the code would be fairly similar. A regex you could use is `/[a-z]+/gi`, which selects every string of 1 or more characters which are alphabetic.

```js
function royalWe(sentence) {
  var replacements = { I: "we", mine: "ours", my: "our", me: "us" };
  return sentence.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, function(word) {
    return replacements[word] || word;
  });
}

console.log(royalWe("I want to go to the store"));
console.log(royalWe("This is my house and you will respect me"));
console.log(royalWe("This is mine"));
console.log(royalWe("Jump for my love"));
```